# GoLang: getting this error upon go install

Tags: go

I am getting this error message when typing 'go install'.

```
root@kali:~/Scripts/Enum/gobuster# go install

go install: no install location for directory /root/Scripts/Enum/gobuster outside GOPATH
For more details see: go help gopath
```

My 'go env' is as following.

```
root@kali:~/Scripts/Enum/gobuster# go env

GOARCH="386"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/root"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_386"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m32 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Can someone help please?
Thank you.

Comment: Your code is not in your GOPATH. It needs to be in a subdirectory of `$GOPATH/src/`. See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Answer (score 1):

@Young Jang,
You need to keep your code in a very specific location, i.e. under the Go's workspace, but also, following a location format to match your repository, 
for example:
~/go/src/github.com/young_jang/gobuster

More details: https://www.goinggo.net/2016/05/installing-go-and-your-workspace.html

Comment: Thank you mpmlj, it is working now. I appreciate your help.